# install local package into virtualenv using setuptools

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I have a virtualenv with multiple little projects in it.  Consider that they are all equal, so my folder structure looks something like this:

```
categorisation_ml/
    categorisation.py
    setup.py
    __init__.py
nlp/
    nlp.py
    setup.py
    __init__.py
etc/
__init__.py
```

I want to install both packages into the same virtualenv so that they are both accessible everywhere within the virtualenv.

Using [this](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html) and [this](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) guide, I have created a `setup.py` script like this (for categorisation in this case):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "categorisation",
    version = "1.0",
    scripts = ['categorisation.py']
)
```

then, I run `python setup.py install` , which seems to complete successfully.
When I `cd` into `nlp/`, enter `python` command line and try
`import categorisation`, I get:
`ImportError: No module named categorisation`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which python is running the `python setup.py install` command? virtualenv or user's python. Was the package installed out side your virtualenv?

Comment: @TomRon python is running out of virtualenv.  No, it seems that the package is getting installed into the virtualenv.  The virtualenv is called `scienv`.  Don't know if it matters, but categorisation.py has the `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang

Comment: What output do you get when running `scienv/bin/pip freeze`? Did you install the package using `scienv/bin/python setup.py install`?

Comment: @TomRon the output contains `categorisation==1.0`.  Yes, I installed it with the virtualenv python

Comment: Did you managed to solve your issue?!

Comment: @leoschet I've quickly answered my own question.  Haven't tested it, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the package structure and setup.py is off.  It should be something like this:

```
irrelevant_package_name/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    categorisation_ml/
        categorisation.py
        __init__.py
    nlp/
        nlp.py
        __init__.py
```

and then the install script looking like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='package_name',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='This is a working setup.py',
    url='http://somesite.com',
    author='Roman',
    author_email='roman@somesite.com',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'numpy',
    ],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Then install it like this:

```
python setup.py install  #(just installs it as is)
python setup.py develop  #(Keeps track of changes for development)
```

If you pip freeze this should come up

```
package_name==1.0.0
```

And then in python imports should look like this:

```
from categorisation_ml import categorisation
from nlp import nlp
```